# Determine whether a program is running under Wine at runtime

Tags: c++, wine

I think the title is self explanatory... I'm writing an application in C++ and I need to determine at runtime if I'm running under Wine (to change the bahavior a little in order to avoid a specific Wine bug).
Is there a programmer-friendly way or should I fiddle with running processes?

Comment: If you have found a bug in Wine, please make sure that you report it.

Comment: @Kerrek That is a compile time constant.

Comment: Are you sure it's a Wine bug and not you relying on non-documented behavior of Windows?

Comment: No, I'm not, but that is unimportant. :) I know how to fix the problem, I just need to know if I'm running under Wine. I'll try with registry.

Comment: Better answer: http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2008-September/069387.html See also http://wiki.winehq.org/DeveloperFaq#head-96551a33b168826cd805c2f62c4ea705ac02f350

Answer (score 17):

This answer is just a copy of user1457056's comment. Since links often die, answers occasionally become useless. I have copied the link content here in order to preserve this useful answer:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    static const char *(CDECL *pwine_get_version)(void);
    HMODULE hntdll = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
    if(!hntdll)
    {
        puts("Not running on NT.");
        return 1;
    }

    pwine_get_version = (void *)GetProcAddress(hntdll, "wine_get_version");
    if(pwine_get_version)
    {
        printf("Running on Wine... %s\n",pwine_get_version());
    }
    else
    {
        puts("did not detect Wine.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are many Wine specific registry entries:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine
```

[Checking if a registry key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343577/checking-if-a-registry-key-exists) has the answer of how to check for these Wine-specific registry keys.

Comment: This is a bad solution, because anyone could create these registry keys on Windows as well.