# OpenCL: Passing a pointer to local memory

Tags: pointers, memory, opencl, gpgpu

I have the following example code:

```
int compute_stuff(int *array)
{
    /* do stuff with array */
    ...
    return x;
}

__kernel void my_kernel()
{
    __local int local_mem_block[LENGTH*MY_LOCAL_WORK_SIZE];
    int result;

    /* do stuff with local memory block */
    result = compute_stuff(local_mem_block + (LENGTH*get_local_id(0)));
    ...
}
```

The above example compiles and executes fine on my NVIDIA card (RTX 2080).
But when I try to compile on a Macbook with AMD card, I get the following error:

```
error: passing '__local int *' to parameter of type '__private int *' changes address space of pointer
```

OK, so then I change the "compute_stuff" function to the following:

```
int compute_stuff(__local int *array)
```

Now both NVIDIA and AMD compile it fine, no problem...
But then I have one more test, to compile it on the same Macbook using WINE (rather than boot to Windows in bootcamp), and it gives the following error:

```
error: parameter may not be qualified with an address space
```

So it seems as though one is not supposed to qualify a function parameter with an address space.  Fair enough.  But if I do not do that, then the AMD on native Windows thinks that I am trying to change the address space of the pointer to `private` (I guess because it assumes that all function arguments will be private?).

What is a good way to handle this so that all three environments are happy to compile it?  As a last resort, I am thinking of simply having the program check to see if the build failed without qualifier, and if so, substitute in the "__local" qualifier and build a second time...  Seems like a hack, but it could work.

Answer (score 1):

The `int*` in `int compute_stuff(int *array)` is `__generic` address space. The call `result = compute_stuff(local_mem_block+...);` implicitly converts it to `__local`, which is allowed according to the [OpenCL 2.0 Khronos specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/genericAddressSpace.html).

It could be that AMD defaults to OpenCL 1.2. Maybe explicitely set `–cl-std=CL2.0` in `clBuildProgram()` or `clCompileProgram()`.

To keep the code compatible with OpenCL 1.2, you can explicitly set the pointer in the function to `__local`: `int compute_stuff(__local int *array)`. OpenCL allows to set function parameters to the address spaces `__global` and `__local`. WINE seems to have a bug here. Maybe inlining the function can solve it: `int __attribute__((always_inline)) compute_stuff(__local int *array)`.

As a last resort, you can do your proposed method. You can detect if it runs on WINE system like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333249/9178992). With that, you could switch between the two code variants without compiling twice and detecting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ProjectPhysX that it appears to be a bug with the WINE implementation.  I also found the following appears to satisfy all three environments:

```
int compute_stuff(__local int * __private array)
{
    ...
}

__kernel void my_kernel()
{
    __local int local_mem_block[LENGTH*MY_LOCAL_WORK_SIZE];
    __local int * __private samples;

    samples = local_mem_block + (LENGTH*get_local_id(0));

    result = compute_stuff(samples);
}
```

The above is explicitly stating that the pointer itself is `private` while the memory it is pointing to is kept in `local` address space.  So this removes any ambiguity.