# Check in Python if Windows registry key already exists

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

Got the following code:

```
    aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE)
try:   
   SetValueEx(aKey,registry_key_name,0, REG_SZ, r"" + folder + "\" + file_name) 
except EnvironmentError:                                          
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."
CloseKey(aKey)
CloseKey(aReg)
```

I would like to add some check if not already exists so only add it if there is no such Key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343577/checking-if-a-registry-key-exists) question I guess the best option is to use [`_winreg.OpenKey`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.OpenKey) and handle the `WindowsError` exception gracefully assuming as registry key non existent.

```
from _winreg import *
exists = True
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
try:
    aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE)
except WindowsError:
    exists = False

try:
    if not exists:
        SetValueEx(aKey,registry_key_name,0, REG_SZ, r"" + folder + "\" + file_name) 
except EnvironmentError:                                          
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."

CloseKey(aKey)
CloseKey(aReg)
```

Comment: @joamagI don't see how it checks to see the key file_name only the folder \Run

Comment: `aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" + "file_name", 0, KEY_WRITE)` is this right?

Comment: Where is the lib `_winreg`?

Comment: @Timo you should do from winreg import * now. It is a built-in python library.