# Python r Preceding Quoted Windows Registry Key

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, registry, startup

I would like to use Python (2.7) to check if a certain registry value exists, and if not create it.

I was finally able to get it to work using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696521/check-in-python-if-windows-registry-key-already-exists):

```
from _winreg import *

key_to_write = r"C:\Python27\Python.exe"

exists = True
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
try:
    aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE)
except WindowsError:
    exists = False

try:
    if not exists:
        SetValueEx(aKey,'Python',0, REG_SZ, key_to_write) 
except EnvironmentError:                                          
    print "Encountered problems writing into the Registry..."

CloseKey(aKey)
CloseKey(aReg)
```

However, in my actual Windows Registry, the Data value is set to (with the r at the beginning):

```
r"C:\Python27\Python.exe"
```

I do not see this preceding r for any other Windows registry data values, but every instance of Python dealing with Windows I have found precedes this value with an r as I have above.

1. Does this r mean something?
2. Do I need to keep this r?
3. Is the r suppose to also appear in the registry entry as I've shown above?

[EDIT]

You guys were write. It turns out I saved the wrong key_to_write variable in my full code. I had:

```
key_to_write = 'r"' + path + '"'
```

It worked fine when I changed it as follows:

```
key_to_write = r'"' + path + '"'
```

For the sake of the question, I thought I had properly defined the variable, so I shortened my code as much as I code with that in mind. Turns out I incorrectly defined it in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses `\` as its path delimiter. Python uses `\` as its string escape character. Clearly these two uses clash.

A Python [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), prefixed with either `r` or `R` stops `\` being interpreted as an escape character:

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase 'n'. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

The reason you encounter raw strings in code that works with paths on Windows is that it allows a string containing Windows path separators to be written using `\` rather than `\\`. So this allows us to write:

```
r"C:\Python27\Python.exe"
```

rather than

```
"C:\\Python27\\Python.exe"
```

One may consider the raw string to be clearer for the reader. At least once the reader understands raw strings.

---

I don't understand what you mean about the `r` prefix appearing in the data written to the registry. That won't happen with the code in the question.

```
>>> print r"C:\Python27\Python.exe"
C:\Python27\Python.exe
>>> print "C:\\Python27\\Python.exe"
C:\Python27\Python.exe
>>> r"C:\Python27\Python.exe" == "C:\\Python27\\Python.exe"
True
```

My guess is that you have manually added data using regedit that is confusing you. Beware also of the registry redirector. If you use 32 bit Python then your code modifies the 32 bit registry view, typically stored under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, I'm still not sure why the `r` prefix appears in the data written to the registry.

Comment: The code in the Q doesn't do that. I bet you did by accident manually.

Answer (score 1):

The "r" is for Python itself. It means that the following string is a raw string. They are used on Windows to help Python understand paths that contain spaces, among other things. You can read more about it here:

- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

I don't know exactly why it's in the Windows Registry though. Python shouldn't care what's in there.

Comment: Thanks, I had mistakenly thought the `r` was suppose to do with something Windows registry related.

Comment: Turns out I incorrectly defined my `key_to_write` variable. I have updated my question accordingly.